# Logout in bottom drawer navigation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, flutter-layout

I want to make logout and settings in bottom of drawer navigation but I have tried many suggestion but doesn't work at all
any suggestion?

This is my drawer navigation

```
Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          _createHeader(),
          _createDrawerItem(icon: Icons.event, text: 'Event', onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.event)
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              _createFooterItem(icon: Icons.event, text: 'Settings', onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.event)),
              _createFooterItem(icon: Icons.event, text: 'Logout', onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.event))
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

this is my widget for header

```
Widget _createHeader() {
    return DrawerHeader(
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: AssetImage('res/images/drawer_header_background.png'))),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              bottom: 12.0,
              left: 16.0,
              child: Text("Flutter Step-by-Step",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
        ]));
  }
```

and this is my widget for footer item

```
Widget _createFooterItem({IconData icon, String text, GestureTapCallback onTap}){
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(icon),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: Text(text),
          )
        ],
      ),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the `ListView` to a `Column` then add a `Expanded` widget with a child `Container`

```
Drawer(
        child: Column( // Changed this to a Column from a ListView
          children: <Widget>[
            _createHeader(),
            ListTile(title: Text('First item')),
            Expanded(child: Container()), // Add this to force the bottom items to the lowest point
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _createFooterItem(
                    icon: Icons.event,
                    text: 'Settings',
                    onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/')),
                _createFooterItem(
                    icon: Icons.event,
                    text: 'Logout',
                    onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/'))
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

- [Dart Pad Example](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: ``Expanded(child: Container()),`` only works with columns widget